# Помогите с подбором железа для разработки под iOS- swift

Tags: swift

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что приобрести для работы с Xcode в 2022 году. Бюджет сильно ограничен, надо понять от каких минимальных системных требований можно отталкиваться, чтобы комфорно учиться и в дальнейшем работать. На курсах яндекс-практикума пишут, что нужен компьютер с системой MacOS Monterey, чтобы установить Xcode 13

Comment: [XCode Minimum requirements](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/#minimum-requirements)

Answer (score 1):

Купите новый Mac mini в минимальной конфигурации, хватит на несколько лет.

https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/

Comment: да, тоже использую как машинку, которая деплоит, но разрабатывать нет уж, простите. M1 чип не то, что дейстивтельно нужно.

Comment: M1 уже везде, чем он не устраивает?

Comment: скоростью работы и необходимостью прослоек

Comment: например танцы с бубнами для react naitve https://medium.com/timeless/starting-react-native-project-in-apple-mac-m1-chip-system-28da0c1f2132

Comment: Все тесты показывают, что у М1 выше скорость чем у Intel. Проблемы с совместимостью так или иначе решены, уже М2 вышел.

Answer (score 0):

Советую приобрести MacBook Air M1/M2 с 16 гб ОЗУ (и желательно 512 ПЗУ), тянет всё очень хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Использую MacBook Air M1 8/256. Думая это самый лучший выбор для новичка с ограниченным бюджетом. Учиться очень комфортно.